# Scala: Is this a mistake in the LinkedListLike trait?

Tags: scala, insert, linked-list, scala-2.8, scala-collections

This is from the source of the Scala standard library from 2.8.1

```
  /** Append linked list `that` at current position of this linked list
   *  @return the list after append (this is the list itself if nonempty,
   *  or list `that` if list this is empty. )
   */
  def append(that: This): This = {
  @tailrec
    def loop(x: This) {
      if (x.next.isEmpty) x.next = that
      else loop(x.next)
    }
    if (isEmpty) that
    else { loop(repr); repr }
  }

  /** Insert linked list `that` at current position of this linked list
   *  @note this linked list must not be empty
   */
  def insert(that: This): Unit = {
    require(nonEmpty, "insert into empty list")
    if (that.nonEmpty) {
      next = next.append(that)
    }
  }
```

Shouldn't this last line be `next = that.append(next)`? (i.e put the rest of this linked list at the end of the list we're inserting?

If not, why not? The code currently appends the list we're inserting on the end of the current one - i.e. same as apppend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a [known bug](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4080).

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable._
import scala.collection.mutable._

scala> val foo = LinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4)
foo: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> foo.next insert LinkedList(5, 6, 7, 8)

scala> foo
res2: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

If it's suppose to insert `LinkedList(5, 6, 7, 8)` in the "current position," the final result should be `LinkedList(1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. 2.8.1 only, it seems. Maybe I'm beginning to understand this Scala thing :)